# How can I tie my laces so they don't come undone?

Tags: knots, shoes

This might seem like a silly question but this is a constant issue for me when hiking or even in general. I have "double" looped my laces but I actually really hate it because it's a pain to untie. Is there a way I can tie my laces so they don't come undone AND so they can be undone by pulling the two laces like normal?

Comment: Ian's Shoelace Site: Surgeon's knot http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/surgeonknot.htm

Comment: Have you tried the [heel lock](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=heel+lock)? It's not as easy to untie as your _normal_ knot but it stays tight even if the _top knot_ comes loose.

Comment: Are you currently tying a slipped square knot (which is usually pretty secure), or a slipped granny (which isn't)?

Comment: @BenCrowell Hmm, i believe the knot I am currently using is the slipped square knot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all if you are really interested in tying your shoes, check out [Ian's Shoelace Site](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/index.htm). All credit for the imagery used here and most of the information given goes to the author Ian Fieggen.

For me the requirements to my shoelace knot are the same as yours (and probably most of everyone's): Secure but still quick to tie and untie.

The [Double Shoelace Knot](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/doubleknot.htm) you mentioned is very common but in my opinion completely useless. It is not more secure than a simple knot. It is just a simple knot done twice, so it has the get undone twice. Plus it is cumbersome to open.

The one knot I use is a slight variation from the [Better Bow Shoelace Knot](http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/betterbowknot.htm). Until the following step you do it the same way:
[image: same Steps]
Instead of going through the first yellow loop as originally shown in the picture below you bypass the yellow loop and go directly through the middle (shown in red, added by myself). So this variation is essentially a standard knot with an extra loop.
[image: variaton]
This is much less fiddly than the original version and is still secure enough (at least I never noticed one getting loose). Untying is very simple, just poll on a loose end.

Comment: I used the content from Ian's Shoelace Site according to his statement "Generally, I'm pretty agreeable to others passing on this knowledge by using portions of the content of this website provided that you simply credit Ian's Shoelace Site as the source or myself (Ian Fieggen) as the author." in the section "Website Content" of http://www.fieggen.com/shoelace/info.htm.

Comment: [Ian Fleming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Fleming)?! :O

Comment: @Liam The mind of humans is a curious thing - they share in common just the first letter of their surname... Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a knot, how about a shoelace buckle?

Simply pull the laces through with the button pushed in, and then release and let it hold them. To take the shoes off, push the button and pull the laces through to create enough slack to remove.

Comment: This would be great for hiking but I don't think it would go well with my business casual clothes during the week. It would definitely work but probably not very "stylish". This is mainly why I'm interested in a knot.